# send attachments and data in form in an email with php

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

**This is my PHP code**

and my html form is below where i want to get the data from name , email, phone number fields  and file attachment.

Now i tried to get the file attached ( without other information entered) in live server environment  i am also getting and attachment in mail as different format (like i have send a word doc but the word file is in dat format which doesn't display any data in word file)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        //The form has been submitted, prep a nice thank you message
        $output = '<h1>Thanks for your file and message!</h1>';
        //Set the form flag to no display (cheap way!)
        $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

        //Deal with the email
        $to = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Details and file attachments ';

        $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
        $attachment = (file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

        $headers = "From: xxxxxx@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
```

This is my html file suggest me how to modify the code for getting the values of other field as well to email

```
    <td height="12"> <?php echo $output; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" <?php echo $flags;?>>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Submit your interest</legend>
                <p><label class="title" for="name">Your name:</label>
                     <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br /></p>
                <p>  <label class="title" for="email">Your email:</label>
                     <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
                <p>  <label class="title" for="phone">Your phone:</label>
                     <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone"></p>
                <p><label for="location" class="title">Total Experience :</label>
                     <select name="location" id="location">
                         <option value="ny">1</option>
                         <option value="il">2</option>
                         <option value="ca">3+</option>
                     </select></p>
                <span class="title">Upload your resume</span>
                <input type="file" name="resume" /> 
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send"></div>
        </form></td>
```

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use phpmailer or swiftmailer. Especially since you're stuffing the RAW contents of the file into the email, yet claiming it's base64-encoded...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> ```

Your headers are saying the data is in `base64` format, but the actual content is raw binary. Try using `base64_encode($attachment)` before including the body.

---

That said, please don't do this manually. A library would take care of all this for you as has been mentioned in the comments.